# Python - Select row in NumPy array where multiple conditions are met

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

My program contains many different NumPy arrays, with various data inside each of them. An example of an array is:

```
x = [5, 'ADC01', Input1, 25000], # Where [TypeID, Type, Input, Counts]
    [5, 'ADC01', Input2, 40000]
```

From separate arrays I can retrieve the value of `Type` and `Input`. I then need to say

`Counts = x[0,3] where Type = 'ADC01' and Input = 'Input2'`

Obviously it would not be wrote like this. For the times that I have only needed to satisfy one condition, I have used:

```
InstType_ID = int(InstInv_Data[InstInv_Data[:,glo.inv_InstanceName] == Instrument_Type_L][0,glo.inv_TypeID])
```

Here, it looks in array(InstInv_Data) at the 'InstanceName' column and finds a match to Instrument_Type. It then assigns the 'TypeID' column to InstType_ID. I basically want to add an `and` statement so it also looks for another matching piece of data in another column.

Edit: I just thought that I could try and do this in two separate steps. Returning both `Input` and `Counts` columns where `Type-Column = Type`. However, I am unsure of how to actually return two columns, instead of a specific one. Something like this:

```
Intermediate_Counts = (InstDef_Data[InstDef_Data[:,glo.i_Type] == Instrument_Type_L][0,(glo.i_Input, glo.i_Counts])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `a & b` to perform element-wise AND for two boolean arrays `a`, `b`:

```
selected_rows = x[(x[:,1] == 'ADC01') & (x[:,2] == 'Input2')]
```

Similarly, use `a | b` for OR and `~a` for NOT.

Comment: Thanks, I attempted to do something similar to this but I  got confused with where to put brackets. That worked great!